# If A ="contact" and B = "" return "XXX" but if A = "contact" and B isn't blank return "Video/Audio"

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, nested-if, ifs

If A4 ="contact" and B4 = "" return "XXX" but if A4 = "contact" and B4 isn't blank return "Video/Audio" in c4

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OH2i45NyRBThFBMQJ_lYbMtpmYAAzOm0FRp5a1DBOm4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF((A4:A="contact")*(B4:B=""), "XXX", 
 IF((A4:A="contact")*(B4:B<>""), "Video/Audio", )))
```

[image]